# converting each cell of csv file (categorical data) into boolean format

Tags: python, csv, categorical-data

I have a CSV file with categorical data (e.g., gender) that I'm trying to convert into a boolean format (male = 1, female = 2, etc.), for which I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
v = DictVectorizer(sparse = True)
D = [ { 'k': 1, 'gender': 'Female' }, 
      { 'k': 2, 'gender': 'Male' },
      { 'k': 3, 'gender': 'NULL' } ]
X = v.fit_transform(D)
```

Although this works fine, I cannot iterate it over each required cell of the specific column (e.g., gender in this case). The data looks like this:

```
patient_id DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH       race  gender     marital_status

11511                        20      Other    Male            Unknown   
9882613                      25    Unknown  Female            Unknown   
32190339                     13  Caucasian  Female            Married   
32190339                     13  Caucasian  Female            Married
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot iterate it over the required cell?"

Comment: @fdsa i want to convert the whole columns of categorical data into usable numeric form. That is what I mean by "each required cell".

Comment: Can you add the part of your code that uses the python CSV module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?

Comment: @fdsa I tried doing `df['gender_num'] = df['gender'].apply(X)` but it doesn't work. The error message says `TypeError: 'csr_matrix' object is not callable`.

Comment: either that or I can do
`for diagnosis, age in zip(df['diagnosis_id'].apply(X), df['age_in_years'].apply(X)):
       
W_parameter.append([float(diagnosis)])
      
Y_parameter.append(float(age))`